# Как пропустить выходные и праздники на графике

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

x = pd.read_csv('file.txt',index_col='Date',
                     parse_dates=True,
                     infer_datetime_format=True)
x['close'].plot(grid=True)
plt.show()
```

Делаю отрисовку данных. Обнаружил, что где нет данных тоже идет отрисовка.
Как мне пропустить данные, которых нет.
По аналогии с C# нужно создать массив с индексами вместо дат и присваивать меткам даты для отображения. Как сделать не пойму, опыта мало.

Comment: Можете выложить пример данных на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: Вам обязательно нужен линейный график? Столбчатая диаграмма в вашем случае не подойдет?

Comment: Это котировки. Дело в том, что пробовал отрисовку в виде свечей и очень долго грузятся.  Поэтому решил одну цену рисовать в раз 15 быстрее получается. Данных очень, много больше 9000.  https://transfiles.ru/t1qi8 вот здесь размещал сам график https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54023250/how-to-add-scrollbar-to-the-chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это соответствует "природе" линейного графика когда на оси `X` - даты. При отображении временного ряда нельзя пропускать даты, т.к. это приведет к искажению графика. Поэтому у вас есть следующие варианты:

1. рисовать как есть:

   ```
   In [122]: df[['Close']].plot(grid=True)
   Out[122]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x150568cb588>
   ```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. в качестве оси `X` использовать числовой ряд:

   ```
   In [121]: df[['Close']].reset_index(drop=True).plot(grid=True)
   Out[121]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x15056ef8320>
   ```

после этого можно самому [изменить подписи `xlabels`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel.html)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS для такого длинного временного ряда пропуски выходных и праздничных дней - незаметны.

---

Игрушечный набор данных - биржевые данные по акциям `APPLE` за 1980 - 2018 года (9594 записи):

```
In [118]: import pandas_datareader.data as web

In [119]: df = web.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', '1980-01-01', '2019-01-01')

In [120]: df.shape
Out[120]: (9594, 6)

In [125]: df
Out[125]:
                  High         Low        Open       Close       Volume   Adj Close
Date
1980-12-12    0.515625    0.513393    0.513393    0.513393  117258400.0    0.023106
1980-12-15    0.488839    0.486607    0.488839    0.486607   43971200.0    0.021900
1980-12-16    0.453125    0.450893    0.453125    0.450893   26432000.0    0.020293
1980-12-17    0.464286    0.462054    0.462054    0.462054   21610400.0    0.020795
1980-12-18    0.477679    0.475446    0.475446    0.475446   18362400.0    0.021398
...                ...         ...         ...         ...          ...         ...
2018-12-24  151.550003  146.589996  148.149994  146.830002   37169200.0  146.830002
2018-12-26  157.229996  146.720001  148.300003  157.169998   58582500.0  157.169998
2018-12-27  156.770004  150.070007  155.839996  156.149994   53117100.0  156.149994
2018-12-28  158.520004  154.550003  157.500000  156.229996   42291400.0  156.229996
2018-12-31  159.360001  156.479996  158.529999  157.740005   35003500.0  157.740005

[9594 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: Как изменить подписи в моем случае, чтобы даты поставить вместо индексов, я так понимаю это возможно?

Comment: @user287629, это возможно, но задача эта нетривиальная - в зависимости от длины временного ряда подписи надо форматировать по-разному. Посмотрите как это делает Pandas в исходниках...

Comment: Пробовал сделать так "plt.xlabel(x['Date'])" не получилось

Comment: Если не трудно покажите, как вместо индексов теперь даты поставить. На C# мне этого никто не смог подсказать, но сам я два месяца в нете рылся, чтобы найти решение.  Не хочется на Python столько времени потерять.